# Machine Vision 8bit Bayer RGGB to RGB in Open CV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently trying to convert an 8bit Raw color image to 8 bit RGB. 
i get a channel error it expect the Bayer to be 1 channel.

i am using the following code.

```
if (convertBayerChckBox->Checked)
        {
            try{
                cv::Mat temp(imgOriginal.rows, imgOriginal.cols, CV_8UC3);
                imgOriginal.copyTo(temp);
                cv::cvtColor(temp, imgOriginal, CV_BayerRG2BGR);
            }
            catch (const cv::Exception& ex)
            {
                std::cout << "EXCEPTION: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
                errLog << "EXCEPTION: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
            }
        }
```

then i am getting the following exception: 
EXCEPTION: ......\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:4194: error: (-215) scn == 1 && dcn == 3 in function cv::cvtColor

I am not sure how else to convert from Bayer to RGB

Comment: I deleted the answer since I got the question wrong. What's the type of `imgOriginal`? How many channels?

Comment: It has 3 Channels and is read from an avi video file that is encoded in 8 bit raw RGGB Bayer

Comment: And why is it a 3 channel if it's 8 bit bayer encoded? it should be 1 channel

Comment: i actually just figured that. 
i am using a point grey Chameleon3 camara and the Flycapture sdk to capture a video recording into an AVI file. 

so maybe it is more of a question for the point grey support

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the data pointer of your input Mat to your destination pointer.
Here is a sample program to convert your bayer image to RGB. Here I've used buffer from a file. You can use your camera frame buffer. Hope this helps!

```
Mat mSource_Bayer(Size(m_IWidth,m_IHeight),CV_8UC1);
Mat mSource_Bgr(Size(m_IWidth,m_IHeight),CV_8UC3);

FILE *fp = NULL;
uchar *imagedata = NULL;
int framesize = m_IWidth * m_IHeight;

//Open raw Bayer image.
fp = fopen(FileName_S.c_str(), "rb");

//Memory allocation for bayer image data buffer.
imagedata = (uchar*) malloc (sizeof(uchar ) * framesize);

//Read image data and store in buffer.
fread(imagedata, sizeof(uchar ), framesize, fp);

mSource_Bayer.data= imagedata;

fclose(fp);

int Selection= m_BayerFormat.GetCurSel();

if(Selection==0)
    cvtColor(mSource_Bayer, mSource_Bgr, CV_BayerBG2BGR);//Perform demosaicing process
else if(Selection==1)
    cvtColor(mSource_Bayer, mSource_Bgr, CV_BayerGB2BGR);//Perform demosaicing process
else if(Selection==2)
    cvtColor(mSource_Bayer, mSource_Bgr, CV_BayerRG2BGR);//Perform demosaicing process
else if(Selection==3)
    cvtColor(mSource_Bayer, mSource_Bgr, CV_BayerGR2BGR);//Perform demosaicing process

imshow("mSource_Bgr",mSource_Bgr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try and implement that and return to you.

Answer (score 0):

Also in order to perform BAYER to RGB conversion I would recommend to use function [SimdBayerToBgr](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/group__bayer__conversion.html#ga9ce7ed295e71acc2cf882622ab78c384) from [Simd Library](https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd). It seems that it function is faster than its analogue from OpenCV (it uses AVX2 and AVX-512).