# Demosaicing RCCG color filter array to RGB with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, colorfilter, demosaicing

I’m trying to convert a raw image from a camera with RCCG *(Red, Clear, Clear, Green)* Color Filter Array into an RGB image.

My idea was to convert RCCG into YCrCg and then into YCrCb. To be able to use the OpenCV method to convert YCrCb to RGB.

This is my first non-working approach in C++ with OpenCV:

```
cv::Mat tmpMat = Mat::zeros(dst.rows, dst.cols, dst.type());

// Debayering from RCCG to RCG
cv::demosaicing(src, tmpMat, cv::ColorConversionCodes::COLOR_BayerBG2RGB); 

float R{};
float C{};
float G{};

float Y{};
float Cr{};
float Cg{};

for (int row = 0; row < tmpMat.rows; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < tmpMat.cols; col++)
    {
        R = tmpMat.at<cv::Vec3w>(row, col)[0];
        C = tmpMat.at<cv::Vec3w>(row, col)[1];
        G = tmpMat.at<cv::Vec3w>(row, col)[2];

        // Convert RCCG to YCrCg
        Y = C;
        Cr = C - 0.299F * R;
        Cg = C - 0.587F * G;

        // Convert YCrCg to YCrCb by swapping Cr and Cg
        dst.at<cv::Vec3w>(row, col)[0] = static_cast<uint16_t>(Y);
        dst.at<cv::Vec3w>(row, col)[1] = static_cast<uint16_t>(Cg);
        dst.at<cv::Vec3w>(row, col)[2] = static_cast<uint16_t>(Cr);
    }
}

cv::cvtColor(dst, dst, cv::ColorConversionCodes::COLOR_YCrCb2BGR);
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Please don't share code as screenshots, it defeats the search function and makes it impossible to reproduce. What you are looking for is 'debayering' (as in Bayer Pattern), maybe check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756723/machine-vision-8bit-bayer-rggb-to-rgb-in-open-cv

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The problem is that OpenCV does not natively support non-RGB CFA like in my case “RCCG” (Red, Clear, Clear, Green). I am therefore trying to achieve this manually using detours.

Comment: OK, much better ! I can't see anything obviously wrong with this, in what way does it not work ? Have you tried looking at the single channels images, if they match what you expect ? (use cv's `namedWindow`/`imshow`)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't send you any pictures of the individual channels at the moment. (The RGB image has a very strong green cast).
But I am pretty sure that the calculation from RCCG to YCrCg / YCrCb is faulty.

The only incomplete source I currently have unfortunately is the following:
https://www.quora.com/How-should-I-calculate-a-Clear-Pixels-Green-component-value-for-a-RCCB-format-picture

I am also not sure if it would be possible to convert RCCG directly to BGR.

Comment: Also, I would like to know if I can just use the pixel values from the RAW image directly or do I need to apply some compensation factor or something?

Comment: raw is linear values. you'll want to apply a gamma map because that's the underlying assumption of most image formats out there. sRGB or whatever else seems most common. if you aren't particular, you can just apply an exponent of 0.45 (1/0.45 ~ 2.22) and be done with it.

Comment: I'm not sure that a sensible approximation of "blue" can be extracted from just red, green, clear (white?). consider the spectra.